# Doctrine - Use single repository class for all entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine ORM 2 to create my model layer. As my project somewhat is just a basic CRUD with functions repeating itself, I would like to create something like a base model for my other entities to inherit, then I can create functions (such as find all) for all my models and thus make it less repetitive.

It seems like in Doctrine, repositories are my best bet. Is it possible to create just one Repository for all my entities, especially since they share many common methods?

Comment: Doctrine 2 automatically creates a repository for each entity type with the expected find/findAll etc methods.  You only need to explicitly create a repository if you want to add additional methods.  In almost all cases these methods will end up being specific to a given entity type.  If you do have some generic functions that are applicable to more than one entity type then you can make your own base repository class and extend from it.  Just be careful to understand the difference between Doctrine's ORM and the Active Record approach.

Comment: ^alright. this helped a lot. Basically what I was doing was making more common methods and modifying the way findAll works to suit my own purpose. If you want to, you can rewrite this as an answer and I'll mark this question answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a single class for all entities, but there are some class inheritance options in Doctrine2. One of them is the so called mapped super class that you could use to create a base model for your entities. You can read about this in [the Doctrine documentation chapter **6.1. Mapped Superclasses**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

There are some limitations though, but this is well explained in the documentation:

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all. Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance features have to be used.

Comment: hmm. I see. I'm no longer planning this approach, though; I'm planning on using repository classes now, though, and making each entity use the same repository for functions related to them. would that be a good approach?

Comment: @dagitab How should I know whether this is good in your particular case. In your question you ask for a base model class and in such case you could use a mapped super class. What is the "best" solution is probably opinion based.

Answer (score -2):

just read http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html.

Doctrine already defined many common methods for you.
By the way,you seems a novice for ORM, so **donot** try to do "create base model for my other entities".

spend some time to understand Doctrine/ORM , otherwise you will feel pain,
ORM/Doctrine is not a novice friendly framework

Comment: There is a mapped super class, it is well documented and and it is totally fine to use this as a base model for entities with common properties.

Comment: @wilt, mate, well documented does not mean you should use it. try to understand what is ORM will help "dagitab" make good decision

Comment: I wrote *"it is well documented **and it is totally fine to use it"***. I really see no problems with using mapped super classes in Doctrine ORM. If you explain in your answer why using it is a bad idea I could comment on that and I might even agree with you. Without any detailed explanation your answer will not be of help to anyone. Not to a novice and not to an expert either.